# How can I change the order of status bar items in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

example:
[image]

I want to rearrange the entries in the VS Code status bar. How can I change the button's order of the status bar in VS Code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is not any official way of doing it. There is a dirty hack you can try, But it may have unexpected outcome.

Yes, You can do that by editing CSS layout file.

1. Goto `.../Microsoft VS
   Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\electron-browser` directory.
2. Open **workbench.main.css** file. Take backup just in case anything goes wrong.
3. Set `.monaco-workbench>.part.statusbar` to use flex using `display:flex`
4. Suppose you want first item to go to 3rd, create CSS class like `.monaco-workbench>.part.statusbar:nth-child(1){order: 3}`
5. Save file and reload VS code

Comment: Is this permanent? What happens after the VSCode update? Will the changes not be overwritten?

Answer (score 6):

From what i know there is no easy way to do this, but they have already reported such a problem in their github repository

You can vote and follow him here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/35744

Answer (score 1):

At the time of this writing, you can't do anything about it.

Currently, the position of status bar items is determined by extension authors only. See [the extension API docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api) for `createStatusBarItem(id: string, alignment?: StatusBarAlignment, priority?: number): StatusBarItem`. For example, [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/main/statusbar-sample/src/extension.ts#L21),

You'll probably be interested in this feature-request issue ticket: [Customizable status bar item locations #35744](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/35744). You can give that issue ticket a thumbs up to show support for it, and subscribe to it to get notified about discussion and progress. Please avoid noisy comments like "+1" / "bump", and consider offering to help implement the change if you know how to do so.